# Why are String, Integer and other wrapper classes considered good keys in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Why String, Integer and other wrapper classes are considered good keys ?

I found below answers -

String, Integer and other wrapper classes are natural candidates of HashMap key, and String is most frequently used key as well because String is immutable and final,and overrides equals and hashcode() method.

Other wrapper class also shares similar property. Immutabiility is required, in order to prevent changes on fields used to calculate hashCode() because if key object return different hashCode during insertion and retrieval than it won't be possible to get object from HashMap. Immutability is best as it offers other advantages as well like thread-safety, If you can  keep your hashCode same by only making certain fields final, then you go for that as well. Since equals() and hashCode() method is used during retrieval of value object from HashMap, its important that key object correctly override these methods and follow contact. If unequal object return different hashcode than chances of collision will be less which subsequently improve performance of HashMap.

Comment: I agree, the other question is about why it works at all. This question is about why Strings are **good** keys

Comment: They're not "wrapper" classes.

Comment: @Boann they are wrapper classes.

Comment: Since I can't answer: 1. Strings work, because they are value objects, which among others means two Strings with the same value will be considered equal. 2. Strings are immutable (as all good value objects). 3. Strings have efficient and reasonable good hashCode implementations. 4. The same is true for 'wrapper classes'

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza They don't wrap any other classes.

Comment: @Boann `Integer` class wraps `int`, `Boolean` class wraps `boolean`, and on...

Comment: @Boann [java.lang.Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html): *The `Integer` class wraps a value of the primitive type `int` in an object.* It's in the official javadoc.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Irrelevant. That's just a limitation of Java's generics. We don't actually *want* to use Integer or Boolean as map keys. We really want to use int and boolean. The reason those are good keys is because they're value types (i.e., immutable).

Comment: @Boann don't be stubborn. It is documented by S̶u̶n̶  Oracle itself.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza On further thought I concede that Integer and Boolean are wrapper classes, although they exist for a subtly different purpose than other wrapper classes one might write. I (mis)read the question as implying that OP considered String a wrapper class, which threw me off. I'm still unsure of the intent of the question: is OP asking why those specific classes are good as keys, or why any classes are good as keys if they wrap other objects, or is the question why we can't do `Map<int,int>`?

Comment: @Boann OP's asking why `String` and `Integer` and other wrapper classes are considered good for keys in `HashMap`. And I agree with you that `String` is not a wrapper class at all. Basically, is for a *good* implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` methods, which are the main methods used in keys in `HashMap` and because they're already there to work with, there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You should formulate that into an answer. It's better than the current answers.

Answer (score 2):

In most `Map` implementations, entries are stored based on the state of the key. If the key changes, there's no way to retrieve the entry given the key.

A `HashMap` deals with a key's `hashCode()` value. If that key's `hashCode()` value is generated from immutable state, it will be constant. Since those types are immutable, their (external) properties are immutable and their `hashCode()` is generated from those properties, a key of any of those types cannot change and this problem becomes a non-issue.

Comment: The fact they're immutable is not the main reason. I can have another class with `final` fields and only use those `final` fields to generate the `hashCode` and evaluate if the instances are `equals` and will accomplish the same behavior.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but just because there are other classes with this property doesn't mean Strings are less suitable.

Comment: @JensSchauder I'm not stating that `String` aren't suitable but that the fact that the class itself is `immutable` is not the main reason.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Edited to clarify that it is the immutability of the properties used in the key mapping algorithm.

Comment: One advantage of the immutability of strings is that the hash code can be **cached** (and this is actually done!). So the lookup using string is particularly efficient, compared to complex and/or mutable objects where the hash code has to be re-computed for each call to `hashCode()`.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following reasons:

1. Strings work, because they are value objects, which among others means two Strings with the same value will be considered equal.
2. Strings are immutable (as all good value objects).
3. Strings have efficient and reasonable good hashCode implementations. Which means usage of them in HashMaps is efficient.

The same is true for 'wrapper classes'